# How to prevent constructor from casting argument types in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, casting

I have a class to store big unsigned numbers and I'd like to allow user to create object using types such as `long long`, `int`, `unsigned int` and so on and also from `string` . I created a constructor `BigNumber(const unsigned long long)` and `BigNumber(const std::string)` but I want to disallow user to use constructions like: `BigNumber('a')` or `BigNumber(true)`. I heard about `explicit` so I decided to write in my class definition following lines:

`explicit BigNumber(const bool) = delete;
explicit BigNumber(const char) = delete;`

Unfortunately when I want to create object like: `BigNumber x(1)` or `BigNumber("1234")` I get error that call of overloaded constructor is ambiguous. I didn't get this message before I wrote these lines with  `explicit`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: `explicit` is not what you think it does; it disallows _implicit_ conversion. For example, it is useful if you have `void foo(BigNumber)`, and want to disallow `foo(123)` or `foo("1234")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using a template:

```
template<typename T,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<T>::value
            && !std::is_same<char, T>::value
            && !std::is_same<bool, T>::value>::type>
explicit BigNumber(T const n);
```

This constructor can't be called with `bool`s or `char`s.

Comment: What about `std::string` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 You can just add a `std::string` overload.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a similar trick as when making classes non-copyable.

```
struct A {
  explicit A(int) { ... }
  explicit A(std::string) { ... }

  // prevent any other types
  template <typename T> A(T) = delete;
};
```

This will require the argument to A's constructor to be exactly `int` or `string`.

```
A a1{1};                      // OK
A a2{std::string("foobar")};  // OK
A a3(1L);                     // Error: use of deleted function 'A::A(T) [with T = long int]'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `explicit` is not what you need. Explicit simply means that constructor will not be used as conversion operator - but it won't stop you from using constructor in construction statements.

The problem you are having is due to the fact that 1 is neither `bool`, `long long int` or `char` - but can be converted to any of those, compiler doesn't know which one. You will have to add a `deleted` constructor for every fundamental type out there (tedious task, indeed) if you really want to block specific integral types.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this.

First let me explain explicit.

Suppose we have this:

```
class Y;
class X {
    X(const Y&);
};
void Z(const X&);
```

This tells the compiler "given a `Y` we can make an `X`" so code like this:

```
Y y;
Z(y);
```

Works, the compiler does this:

```
Y y;
Z(X(y)); /* temporary X constructed here from the y*/
```

Explicit disallows this.

So if you have:

```
class X {
    explicit X(const Y&);
};
```

Then

```
Z(y);
```

Will not work! As you must `explicit`ly construct an `X` from a `Y`.

This is called a conversion constructor, the idea is that you can **freely** convert. This is great when you have something that expects a `string` and give it a `const char*` as it *implicitly* constructs a string and passes that, you're 'suffering' the interplay of the basic types.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to `explicit`.

`BigNumber("1234")` can use `BigNumber(const std::string)` or `BigNumber(const bool)` (the latter should be prefered btw).

So don't provide constructor for `bool` (or provide constructor also for `const char*` (exact match)).